Error in downloadBitmap - java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to: file://data/, Error in reading bitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException
I define iconRef in Angular Nativescript code as:
   <Image #icon />
   @ViewChild("icon", { static: false }) iconRef: ElementRef;

and try dynamically changing image as
   this.iconRef.nativeElement.src=`file:/${this.getfullIconPath(this.iconPath)}`

file .png is present, I'm sure that file present and path is correct. I can see file on Android studio

However I receive error
 Error in downloadBitmap - java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to: file://data/data/...
 Missing Image with resourceID: file://data/data/...
      

What going wrong?
During last 2 days I try to use a lot of other variants, from adding refresh point
 .then((x) => (this.iconRef.nativeElement.src = `${this.iconPath}${"?ts=" + new Date().getTime()}`))

to change folder to ~/assets and, but still failed

image present and can be opened by Android Studio

however upload it to Image control is impossible. Why? Any ideas?
